Определение ближайшего дня рождения сотрудника
Задача: Сотрудники организации
Дан список сотрудников организации, в котором указаны их фамилии, имена и даты рождения. Напишите программу, которая определяет самого молодого сотрудника, празднующего свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней от текущей даты.
Формат входных данных
На вход программе в первой строке подается текущая дата в формате DD.MM.YYYY, в следующей строке вводится натуральное число n — количество сотрудников, работающих в организации. В последующих
n строках вводятся данные о каждом сотруднике: имя, фамилия и дата рождения, разделённые пробелом. Дата рождения указывается в формате DD.MM.YYYY.
Формат выходных данных
Программа должна определить самого молодого сотрудника, празднующего свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней, и вывести его имя и фамилию, разделив пробелом. Если таких сотрудников нет, программа должна вывести текст:
Дни рождения не планируются
Примечание 1. Гарантируется, что у всех сотрудников даты рождения различны.
Примечание 2. Например, для даты 01.11.2021 ближайшими семью днями являются:
02.11.2021, 03.11.2021, 04.11.2021, 05.11.2021, 06.11.2021, 07.11.2021, 08.11.2021
Написал два варианта
1 вариант
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def find_youngest_birthday(employees, current_date):
    # Преобразуем текущую дату в объект datetime
    current_date = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%d.%m.%Y')
    
    # Инициализируем переменные для хранения самого молодого сотрудника и его даты рождения
    youngest_employee = None
    youngest_age = None
    youngest_birthday = None
    
    # Перебираем всех сотрудников
    for employee in employees:
        # Преобразуем дату рождения сотрудника в объект datetime
        birthday = datetime.strptime(employee['birthday'], '%d.%m.%Y')
        
        # Проверяем, празднует ли сотрудник свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней
        if (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year) - current_date).days >= 0 and (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year) - current_date).days <= 7:
            # Рассчитываем возраст сотрудника на момент текущей даты
            age = current_date.year - birthday.year
            if current_date.month < birthday.month or (current_date.month == birthday.month and current_date.day < birthday.day):
                age -= 1
            
            # Если это самый молодой сотрудник, то обновляем переменные
            if youngest_age is None or age < youngest_age:
                youngest_employee = employee
                youngest_age = age
                youngest_birthday = birthday
            elif age == youngest_age and birthday > youngest_birthday:
                youngest_employee = employee
                youngest_birthday = birthday
                
    # Если найден хотя бы один сотрудник, празднующий свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней, то возвращаем его имя и фамилию
    if youngest_employee:
        return f"{youngest_employee['name']} {youngest_employee['surname']}"
    else:
        # Иначе возвращаем текст "Дни рождения не планируются"
        return "Дни рождения не планируются"

# Читаем входные данные
current_date = input()
n = int(input())
employees = []
for _ in range(n):
    name, surname, birthday = input().split()
    employees.append({'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'birthday': birthday})

# Вызываем функцию и выводим результат
print(find_youngest_birthday(employees, current_date))

но при тесте 1
Test input:
14.11.2021
3
Иван Петров 16.11.1995
Петр Сергеев 14.11.1997
Сергей Романов 17.11.1994
Test output:
Петр Сергеев

вместо Иван Петров
2 вариант
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Функция для парсинга даты из строки
def parse_date(date_str):
    return datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d.%m.%Y')

# Чтение текущей даты
current_date_str = input().strip()
current_date = parse_date(current_date_str)

# Определение диапазона дней
start_date = current_date + timedelta(days=1)
end_date = current_date + timedelta(days=7)

# Чтение количества сотрудников
n = int(input().strip())

# Список для хранения ближайших дней рождений
birthdays = []

# Обработка данных сотрудников
for _ in range(n):
    employee_data = input().strip()
    name, surname, birth_date_str = employee_data.split()
    birth_date = parse_date(birth_date_str)
    
    # Получаем день и месяц рождения, устанавливаем год на текущий
    birth_day_month = birth_date.replace(year=current_date.year)
    
    # Проверяем, попадает ли день рождения в диапазон
    if start_date <= birth_day_month <= end_date:
        birthdays.append((birth_day_month, name, surname))

# Если есть дни рождения, определяем самого молодого
if birthdays:
    # Сортировка по дате рождения
    birthdays.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])  # Сортируем по дате
    # Вывод имен самого молодого в диапазоне
    print(birthdays[0][1], birthdays[0][2])  # Молодой — это первый после сортировки
else:
    print("Дни рождения не планируются")

при тесте 4
10.11.2021
5
Иван Петров 11.11.1995
Петр Сергеев 12.11.1992
Сергей Романов 13.11.1996
Роман Григорьев 14.11.1994
Григорий Иванов 15.11.1995

выводит Иван Петров вместо Сергея Романова

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Самый молодой -  у которого дата рождения позже, а не раньше, поэтому во втором варианте нужно выбирать последнего после сортировки (или лямбду сортировки модифицировать, или reverse=True).
В первом, т.к. текущий день не учитывается, нужно строгое сравнение дня
if (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year) - current_date).days > 0


так вроде правильно написано не понимаю что менять 2 часа возился

сортировка по полю даты поставит первым самого старого (его дата же меньше)

по какой именно дате тут их куча

Так, вам в первом варианте Петр Сергеев не нравится? Строго больше сравнение дня сделайте: if (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year) - current_date). days > 0

о чуть помогло сначала сделал все строго появились ошибки в 5 тесте # TEST_5:
12.11.2021
5
Иван Петров 14.10.1995
Петр Сергеев 29.04.1992
Сергей Романов 23.11.1996
Роман Григорьев 19.11.1994
Григорий Иванов 16.07.1995 потом сделал строго только >0 и оставил <=7 но не проходит 8 тест # TEST_8:
29.12.2021
4
Иван Петров 30.12.1995
Петр Сергеев 04.01.1997
Сергей Романов 03.01.1994
Маша Иванова 31.12.1996

У вас переход года не учитывается после birthday.replace(year=current_date.year)

переход года? а как реализовать

Можно попробовать, кроме замены на текущий год, ещё на следующий заменять

попробую что то придумать

Вот ваш первый вариант, доработанный чтобы проходил тест.
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def find_youngest_birthday(employees, current_date):
    # Преобразуем текущую дату в объект datetime
    current_date = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%d.%m.%Y')

    # Инициализируем переменные для хранения самого молодого сотрудника и его даты рождения
    youngest_employee = None
    youngest_age = None
    youngest_birthday = None
    # Перебираем всех сотрудников
    for employee in employees:
        # Преобразуем дату рождения сотрудника в объект datetime
        birthday = datetime.strptime(employee['birthday'], '%d.%m.%Y')

        # Проверяем, празднует ли сотрудник свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней
        diff_date_in_days = (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year)-current_date).days
        if diff_date_in_days < 0:
                    diff_date_in_days = (birthday.replace(year=current_date.year+1)-current_date).days
        if 0 < diff_date_in_days <= 7:
            # Рассчитываем возраст сотрудника на момент текущей даты
            age = relativedelta(current_date, birthday).years

            # Если это самый молодой сотрудник, то обновляем переменные
            if youngest_age is None or age < youngest_age:
                youngest_employee = employee
                youngest_age = age
                youngest_birthday = birthday
            elif age == youngest_age and birthday > youngest_birthday:
                youngest_employee = employee
                youngest_birthday = birthday

    # Если найден хотя бы один сотрудник, празднующий свой день рождения в течение ближайших семи дней, то возвращаем его имя и фамилию
    if youngest_employee:
        return f"{youngest_employee['name']} {youngest_employee['surname']}"
    else:
        # Иначе возвращаем текст "Дни рождения не планируются"
        return "Дни рождения не планируются"


def test_find_youngest_birthday():
    test_case_employees = [{'name': 'Иван', 'surname': 'Петров', 'birthday': '11.11.1995'},
                           {'name': 'Петр', 'surname': 'Сергеев', 'birthday': '12.11.1992'},
                           {'name': 'Сергей', 'surname': 'Романов', 'birthday': '13.11.1996'},
                           {'name': 'Роман', 'surname': 'Григорьев', 'birthday': '14.11.1994'},
                           {'name': 'Григорий', 'surname': 'Иванов', 'birthday': '10.11.1995'}
                           ]
    result = find_youngest_birthday(test_case_employees, '10.11.2021')
    assert result == 'Сергей Романов'
    
test_find_youngest_birthday()
    

Но конечно, код можно сделать более простым и выразительным:
def find_youngest_birthday(employees, current_date):
    # Преобразуем текущую дату в объект datetime
    current_date = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%d.%m.%Y')
    
    def get_diff_in_days(_employee, _current_date):
        _birthday_as_date = datetime.strptime(_employee['birthday'], '%d.%m.%Y')
        _employee['birthday'] = _birthday_as_date
        result = (_birthday_as_date.replace(year=current_date.year)-_current_date).days
        if result < 0:
            result = (_birthday_as_date.replace(year=current_date.year+1)-_current_date).days
        return result
    # ищем сотрудников с датой рождения через 1-7 дней
    employees_in_condition = [e for e in employees if 0< get_diff_in_days(e, current_date) <= 7]
    # оставляем самого молодого
    youngest_employee_in_condition = next(iter(sorted(employees_in_condition, key=lambda e: e['birthday'],reverse=True)), None)

    return youngest_employee_in_condition or "Дни рождения не планируются"


Ваш код работает для дат в конце года?

Теперь да. Спасибо за наводку!
